# Is there a scale, rating, or formula for the 'pleasantness' of a word?

Tags: phonology

I'm wondering, some words sound 'nicer', not taking their associations into account. For example, long vowels and soft endings are considered rounder than hard vowels, like k. (This is the [Bouba/kiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bouba/kiki_effect) effect). They are also considered more pleasant.

On lists of words that people hate, short, hard consonant-ending words tend to appear, like, 'moist', 'snort', 'flap', and 'curd'.

Is there a rating system or formula that quantifies how 'nice' a word is? I think it would be useful for naming things, or helping non-native speakers with word choice.

Comment: This seems related to [phonosemantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_symbolism). Many linguistic concepts in semantics where a continuum is desired are somewhat vague. Like taboo, some are more than taboo than others but to quantify the amount reliably  is difficult. 'Crap' is less taboo than 'shit' and more than 'dung' but by how much? A relative or very rough just-extremes label is probably enough. Sadly most dictionaries will only rarely note the very furthest extremes (like 'shit') if at all.

Comment: There was also a psycho-linguistic study of the effect of F1-F2 placement, and the reversal, F2-F1, and the emotional response. I am still looking for it on-line.

Comment: I like the "kiki"  name Kate better than the "bouba"  Molly. And how are "moist', 'snort', 'flap', and 'curd'   "short, vowel-ending words"? In short  no, there is no  "rating system or formula that quantifies how 'nice' a word is" that has any legitimacy.

Comment: @Cascabel , I really want to see that study.

Comment: I have been looking: unfortunately it was stored on a compu that I burned out last year. I will keep looking for the location of the PDF, and post as an answer. It was part of research I was doing [for this Q](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/316935/knick-knack-and-bric-a-brac), which I never updated.

Comment: @NetHawk: Welcome to English Language & Usage Stack Exchange. It would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts. You should use the [contact form](/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged. In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts. For your information, these are https://english.stackexchange.com/users/216307/nethawk and https://english.stackexchange.com/users/216314/nethawk. You’ll then be able to [edit], comment on, and accept answers to this question.

Comment: I posted an answer with a different study than the one I was looking for: I will keep looking for the other.

Comment: @Cascabel There is the idea that has been kicking around since at least 1903 that "cellar-door" is the most beautiful word in the English language. Luckily the rules of EL&U preclude questions or comments that seek or express mere opinion, so I need not comment on the merits of this assertion. There is an informative discussion of it here:http://www.nytimes.com/2010/02/14/magazine/14FOB-onlanguage-t.html

Comment: Beauty of language is in the ear - and eye - of the beholder. No, you cannot quantify how "nice" a word is because it is a qualitative measurement of people's reactions to it not a quantitative one. So even if many people say they hate some word, this is false objectivism.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31192/to-what-extent-do-english-words-sound-like-what-they-describe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A study was conducted and published at the University of Wisconsin-Madison in 2013, [Inherent Emotional Quality of Human Speech Sounds](http://koenigslab.psychiatry.wisc.edu/pdfs/Myers-Schulz_CogEmo_phoneme.pdf), in which it was demonstrated...

> ...that certain strings of English phonemes have an inherent, non-arbitrary emotional valence which can be predicted on the basis of dynamic changes in acoustic features.

It was partly based on the idea that animal vocalizations with higher formant positions were considered to be smaller organisms and hence less threatening than animals with vocalization with lower formant positions.

To remove any "biasing", nonsense words were used with both upward and downward F1-F2 shifts, and subjects were asked to associate the "words" with pictures, much like in the Kolher study (1929). Examples of the "words" are shown below.

[image]

And this is an example of "words" + pictures:

[image]

The conclusions were that:

> The data presented here effectively ***outline a formula for constructing words and non-words that implicitly conjure positive or negative emotion***. Accordingly we see potential applications of this study to a variety of educational, social, clinical, and marketing contexts.

I do not know if this study has ever been replicated; I will leave that up to you to follow up.

Below is the link to the PDF of the complete Meyers-Shulz study.

http://koenigslab.psychiatry.wisc.edu/pdfs/Myers-Schulz_CogEmo_phoneme.pdf

Comment: This is all about [***“Phonaesthetics*** (from the Greek: φωνή phōnē, "voice-sound"; and αἰσθητική aisthētikē, "aesthetics") is the study of the inherent pleasantness (euphony) or unpleasantness (cacophony) of the sound of certain words, phrases, and sentences.”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonaesthetics)  See also Tolkien’s [**cellar door**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellar_door), but remember that that one probably works better in arrhotic dialects. Tolkien was immensely interested in this; both his two main Elvish languages, Quenya and Sindarin, manifest it quite notably.

Comment: I didn't see it mentioned but I really believe *uck and suck are used because of the way they sound and have little to do with their vulgar or actual meaning.  Perhaps originally it was the shock value for the F word but it's just such a satisfying sound to make when you feel like slamming your fist. (it's a bit of a spitting mouth movement too ?) Anyone have a source supporting my theory?